# FragmentPagerAdapter for beginner

Tags: java, android

First, I'm sorry for my english.

I have create an activity with 3 tabs, those tabs are handle by a FragmentPagerAdapter. But the informations i want to show in my tabs are in the activity.class. I'm a beginner and I don't see how to transfer data from activity.class to the FragmentPagerAdapter

This is for a "know more", when i click on 1 consommer I arrive in this Activity with 3 tabs, in the on create a have a url request to a web API which return JSONObject, i parse this json and get different variable. It's those variables I wan't to put on the FragmentPagerAdapter in the putStrings

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] libelle = { "Coordonnées", "Contacts", "TI" };

        ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Coordonne_client coordonneClient = new Coordonne_client();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("nomCli", "");
                    coordonneClient.setArguments(bundle);

                    return coordonneClient;

                case 1:
                    Contacts_client contacts_client = new Contacts_client();
                    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                    bundle2.putString("message", "Fragment: Liste de contact");
                    bundle2.putString("test", "message test");
                    contacts_client.setArguments(bundle2);

                    return contacts_client;

                case 2:
                    Tickets_incidents tickets_incidents = new Tickets_incidents();
                    Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
                    bundle3.putString("message", "Fragments = Liste des TI du client");
                    tickets_incidents.setArguments(bundle3);

                    return  tickets_incidents;

                default:

                    return null;


            }


        }



        @Override
        public int getCount(){

            return 3;

        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return  libelle[position];
        }
    }
```

And the activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_client);


        viewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

       String leclient = (String) extras.get("leClient");
       queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(InfoClient.this);
       url = "http://host/select/infoClient/"+leclient;
       stringRequest = new StringRequest(GET, url, InfoClient.this, InfoClient.this);
       queue.add(stringRequest);

    }

@Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {


        try{


            JSONObject client = new JSONObject(response);

            String nomClient = client.get("NOM").toString();
            String adresseClient = client.get("ADRESSE").toString();
            String codePostalClient = client.get("CODEP").toString();
            String villeClient = client.get("VILLE").toString();
            String telClient = client.get("TEL").toString();





        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Thanks for your help, hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution, In my ViewPagerAdapter, i add a function add(), in parameter i take all the variables and i call this function before

```
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

So now I can use them, thanks

Answer (score 0):

put your date inside a bundle then use
fragment.setArguments(bundle contains data)

Comment: I think I have understand but can you tell me how to get the arguments in the fragment, I try something but I have some errors

Comment: I have tried but my problem is that I handle my fragments in the ViewPagerAdapter class, so I have to send information in this class, but don't know how to do ...